# How to test java code (the source itself)

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing

I have two files in my Maven project which belong to each other. One is Java code in `src/main/java`, the other is a JSON file in `src/main/resources` folder.

I want to make sure that if a property is added or updated in the Java code, that also the according JSON file is updated and vice versa. My idea is to write a unit test which fails in such cases.

For most properties I could scan the Java code using reflection, but when it comes to generics (for example a property of type `List<Foo>`) I'm stuck because even reflection does not know about `Foo`.

So my idea is to parse the Java source itself. I've never done this before and don't know what to search for.

Comment: If you have Java code that uses a property that's not in the JSON file, then won't the tests for that particular piece of code fail?  Having an additional test to double up on this seems like FAR too much trouble for very little gain.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Yes. I want that the tests fail if the property is in the java code and not in the json. The json is a configuration file that contains some parameters for every property. And I want to ensure that there is a config for every property. I don't convert a java object into some json or something like this.

Comment: I'm saying that if you've written appropriate unit tests for the methods that use the properties, then you already have tests  that will fail if you've missed a property from the JSON file.  You don't need to double up by having one big test that checks all the properties.